# I don't have any error but the search is not working Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I write this method to make a search but I don't know what I am missing because this is not working.
I can select an element in the array list but not able to search.

Here is the code

```
private valueItems;
searchTerm;
productDropdownOptions: DropdownOption [] = [
    {key: '', value: ''}
  ];
```

This is constructor:

```
this.store.select('valueItemDatabase').subscribe(state => {
      this.valueItems = state.valueItems;
      state.valueItems.forEach(product => {
        if (product.type === ValueItemType.PRODUCT) {
          this.productDropdownOptions.push({value: `${product.businessId} - ${product.name}`, key: product.id });
        }
      });
    });

      filterCountryList() {
        if (this.searchTerm) {
          const _term = this.searchTerm.toLowerCase();
          this.productDropdownOptions.filter(function (el: any) {
            return el.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(_term.toLowerCase()) > -1;
          });
        }
        return this.;
      }

      // set selected country
       selectCountry(value) {
        this.searchTerm = value;
      }

<app-input-field label="Filter Name/ID" style="float: left" orientation="top">
              <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (keyup)="filterCountryList()">
            </app-input-field>
             <div class="table-item">
              <div class="table-item-array" *ngFor="let c of productDropdownOptions" (click)="selectCountry(c.value)" [(ngModel)]="selectedItemId" ngDefaultControl>
                <span>{{c.value}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I am expecting at the input field when write a word the array should find lists with that word I wrote.
What do you suggest me to edit in the productDropdownOptions

Comment: try `this.productDropdownOptions = this.productDropdownOptions.filter(function (el: any) {...});`

Comment: @TadijaBagarić When invoked repeatedly, that would gradually empty out the `productDropdownOptions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing anything with the result of your `filter()` operation.

A solution would be to maintain two lists:

```
searchTerm;
productDropdownOptions: DropdownOption[] = [/* ... */];
filteredProductDropdownOptions = productDropdownOptions;

filterCountryList() {
  if (this.searchTerm) {
    const searchTerm = this.searchTerm.toLowerCase();

    this.filteredProductDropdownOptions = this.productDropdownOptions.filter(el =>
      el.value.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm));
    }
  } else {
    this.filteredProductDropdownOptions = productDropdownOptions;
  }
}
```

And then use the `filteredProductDropdownOptions` in your template.

Comment: It is working man, I have accepted your answer, thanks you save my life.

Comment: I need and something else, can i ask how to do it, if yes let me know ?

Comment: Just ask a new question on SO.

Comment: I cannot make this, need to wait 90 minutes.

Comment: I have ask the question here is the SO.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49815756/how-to-set-the-value-when-i-click-one-list-in-the-array-angular-4