# I am trying to bind an ID and the name in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to make a bind, so I have a list of elements in the array the have the key like id and the value like name.
So I created a search input field and there when I type name it makes a search in the array, but the problem is when I click this bind should work like this, it clicks that list in the array with the id which in my case it is key and in the input field it shows me the name which in my case it is value.
This is showing me the name(value) but then is not selecting the key or id and the application is not working.
Below is the code.

HTML-Template

```
 <app-input-field label="Filter Name/ID" labelWidth="300px" style="float: left" orientation="top">
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (keyup)="filterProductList()">
  </app-input-field>
      <div class="table-item">
          <div class="table">
            <div class="table-item-array" *ngFor="let c of filteredProductDropdownOptions" (click)="selectProduct(c)"  ngDefaultControl>
                <span>{{c.value}}</span>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is the TS

```
 searchTerm;
 productDropdownOptions: DropdownOption [] = [
    {key: '', value: ''}
  ];
  filteredProductDropdownOptions = this.productDropdownOptions;
```

Here is the search method.

```
filterProductList() {
    if (this.searchTerm) {
      const searchTerm = this.searchTerm.toLowerCase();
      this.filteredProductDropdownOptions = this.productDropdownOptions.filter(el =>
        el.value.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm));
  } else {
     this.filteredProductDropdownOptions = this.productDropdownOptions;
}
  }
```

Here is when I select an element in the list of the array.

```
selectProduct(complexObject) {
this.searchTerm = complexObject.value;
```

Comment: How do you bind your object to your HTML-template?

Comment: Share html code

Comment: I edited the question there you can find the HTML-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, bind the complex object, not just it's value:

```
selectProduct(complexObject) {
this.searchTerm = complexObject;
```

Modify your filter to only filter the value:

```
filterProductList() {
    if (this.searchTerm) {
      const searchTerm = this.searchTerm.value.toLowerCase();
      this.filteredProductDropdownOptions = this.productDropdownOptions.filter(el =>
        el.value.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm));
  } else {
     this.filteredProductDropdownOptions = this.productDropdownOptions;
}
  }
```

Comment: I edited the code and now you can find the HTML, so maybe you can find a way how this works.

Comment: it is working but in the input it is showing me now the Id I want to show the name there is this possible and I will make your answer as accepted now.

Comment: Strange... if you leave the`<span>{{c.value}}</span>` untouched, it should display the name. Did you change that as well? You should only ony change the c.id in the click handler

Comment: Here is what I changed I will update the question. I dint touch the <span>{{c.value}}</span> but i putted more code in the question you can see what is this searchTerm

Comment: ah, so your problem is that you want to store the id AND the Value as well in this.searchTerm? 
Then, you should not bind the key to it, but rather use the key-value object itself. See the update#2

Comment: I have made your question like accepted but I didn't finish this when I click like you have edited your question it is showing me [object Object] what to do ??

Comment: what does `console.log(complexObject.id, ' - ', complexObject.value);` show you?

Comment: Shows me the ID and the Value but at the input field shows me like[object, Object]
I want to select ID and in the input field to show me the name.

Comment: This is showing me the value that is correct in the input field but not selecting complexObject.key and for this the application is not working, do you have any idea how this to work, like this so the name is showing there but the id key is selected.

Comment: You are not providing your full code, only parts of it. I do not understand what you want to achive, but you cannot do multiple things with one object. You want to bind to the ID? then object.id. You want to bind the Value? then object.value. You want to do both? You must re-write your code and bind the complexObject itself, and then reference xy.id and xy.value. I do not see the code, I do not understand what you want to do, and  I strongly belive you do not understand the basic concept of angular binding styles... cannot help you with that.

Comment: Do you wan't to see the full code of ts and HTML if yes i will put it there, I am learning the angular basic I am not a senior.

Comment: Yes, that would help. And please try to describe what you want to do with the input, the object you bind it to, and what do you want to see on the webpage. Create a minimal example in plunker http://plnkr.co/ if you can.

Comment: I have updated the answer and there puted all the code, but to create a plunker I don't know really good, sorry.

Comment: created a new answer. This way, you display the object.value. You filter for the object.value. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169085/discussion-between-azh-and-forestg).